# Adding text in SQL query using for loop

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, sql-update

By reading the topic I suppose it sounds rather strange. It is, kind of. What I want is to add text in a SQL query by using a for loop. My current code looks like this for the moment:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE hon_setups SET hidTop = '"
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($selectedSetupTop); $i++) {
        echo 'OR imageId = 1 ';
    }
"'") or die(mysql_error());
```

As you may see I want to add (in this example) the text "OR imageId = 1 " until *$i* is the same value as *$selectedSetupTop*. The *$selectedSetupTop* variable is sent from a previous page. The example above is a script page. Tell me if you need better explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I sure don't understand the question. I am confused by want to add then using and update statement.  You  want multiple entries of 'OR imageId = 1' in a column named hidTOP?

Comment: @BalamBalam Never mind, I solved it in another way. Thanks for taking interest though! =)

Answer (score 4):

Ok. So your 'echo' is a fixed string. you'd end building a query that looks like

```
UPDATE hoN_setups SET hidTop = ' OR imageID = 1 OR imageID = 1 OR imageID = 1'
```

I'm assuming you want to use some IDs stored in the $selectedSetupTop array, which'd you'd do like this:

```
$values = implode(',', $selectedSetupTop);
$sql = "UPDATE hon_setups SET hidTop = somevalue WHERE imageID IN ($values);";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```